# How can simplex coordinates simplify this integration?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, coordinate-systems

My textbook defines simplex coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by:

$\Phi: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n , (x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\Phi(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ where:

\begin{align*}
x_1 & =u_1(1-u_2), & u_1 & =x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_n \\[6pt]
x_2 & =u_1u_2(1-u_3), & u_1 & =\frac{\phantom{x_1 + {}} x_2+\cdots +x_n}{x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n} \\
&\,\,\, \vdots & & \,\,\, \vdots \\
x_k & =u_1u_2\cdots u_k(1-u_{k+1}), & u_k & =\frac{\phantom{x_{k-1}+{}}x_k+\cdots +x_n}{x_{k-1} + x_k+\cdots + x_n} \\
& \,\,\, \vdots & & \,\,\, \vdots \\
x_n & =u_1u_2\cdots u_n,  & u_n & =\frac{\phantom{x_{n-1}+{}}x_n}{x_{n-1}+x_n}
\end{align*}

> Problem:
>
> A tetrahedron ($3$-simplex) is  given by the vertices $(0,0,0)$,
> $(1,0,0)$, $(0,2,0)$, $(0,0,3)$. Find $\int _T xz+y^2 \, \mathrm{d}V$.

I know that I have to use the [transformation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables). But how do I describe the tetrahedron with  the new coordinate system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Your tetrahedron is given by
$$T = \{(x,2y,3z) : x,y,z \ge 0, x+y+z \le 1\}.$$
New coordinates $(u,v,w)$ are given by
$$\begin{cases} u = x+y+z, \\ v = \frac{y+z}{x+y+z}, \\ w = \frac{z}{y+z}\end{cases} \qquad \begin{cases} x = u(1-v), \\ y=uv(1-w), \\ z=uvw\end{cases}$$
so check that
$$T=\{(x,2y,3z) : (x,y,z) = \Phi(u,v,w),  0 \le u,v,w \le 1\}) = \Psi([0,1]^3)$$

where $$\Psi(u,v,w) = (u(1-v),2uv(1-w),3uvw).$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on your though process regarding $T$? A plane through $(1,0,0)$, $(0,2,0)$, $(0,0,3)$ is given by $6x+3y+2z=6$ which is equivalent to $x+0.5y+\frac{1}{3}z=1$. Why did you choose $(x,\boxed{2}y,\boxed{3}z)$?

Comment: @Analysis The two expressions are equivalent:$$\{(x,2y,3z): x,y,z \ge 0, x+y+z\le 1\} = \left\{(x,y,z) : x,y,z \ge 0, x+\frac12 y + \frac13z \le 1\right\}.$$
Anyway, your tetrahedron is a $3$-[simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) with vertices $(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,3)$ so it is given by $$\{t_0(0,0,0)+t_1(1,0,0)+t_2(0,2,0)+t_3(0,0,3) : t_0,t_1,t_2,t_3 \ge 0, t_0+t_1+t_2+t_3 = 1\}$$
which simplifies to my expression above.

Comment: Is there a reason as to why you sometimes use $\Psi$ and sometimes $\Phi$?

Comment: @Analysis They are different functions, we have $$\Phi(u,v,w)=(u(1-v),uv(1-w),uvw), \quad \Psi(u,v,w)=(u(1-v),2uv(1-w),3uvw).$$

Comment: I see, thanks. :)